# Visual studio 2017 disable css formatting unnecessary spaces

Tags: visual-studio

I have a problem when I trying to format css code. Visual studio gives me unnecessary spaces in css

Before format css code in visual studio :

```
.test-parent {
}

.test-parent .test-child {
}

.test-parent .test-child .test-child-child {
}
```

After format css code in visual studio :

```
.test-parent {
}

    .test-parent .test-child {
    }

        .test-parent .test-child .test-child-child {
        }
```

Is it possible to disable unnecessary spaces in visual studio 2017 ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I believe this feature is called "Hierarchical Indentation".

You should be able to disable it by completing the following.

- Click the Tools menu
- Click Options...
- Scroll down and expand Text Editor
- Scroll down and expand CSS
- Select Advanced
- Set Hierarchical indentation to "Off".

This should stop Visual Studio formatting your CSS in the nested format.